# changing internal program icons and text

Tags: exe, reverse-engineering

Hello everyone is this any way to change this icons and text in Freetube  I want to make the logo more beautiful and cooler .I'm straggling how to change it I've tried resource hacker and nothing happened

[image: 1]

Comment: yes there is ... edit the source code and compile

Comment: @jsotola bruh

Answer (score 1):

The software is literally open source:
https://github.com/FreeTubeApp/FreeTube

There is no need to modify the compiled binary.
Clone the repository (maybe fork it before, so you can retain your changes and merge newer commits from upstream when wanted), do you changes, then compile it.

See https://docs.freetubeapp.io/development/building-from-source for how to build it yourself.